# Is a question on topic if the code works locally but errors when submitted to a coding site?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, questions, broken-code

This is about a recently posted question: [Codejam 2018 - Getting confusing runtime error](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210016/codejam-2018-getting-confusing-runtime-error)

The OP claims it works for him locally, but generates a Runtime Error on the Google Code Jam website itself.

Is my understanding correct that, as the OP is asking *to find a problem in his program* and not to improve the code itself, this is off-topic for Code Review?